# WP_Error on attribute + term insert

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, terms

I want to add a product attribute (wc_create_attribute) & assigned terms (wp_insert_term) via the functions.php.

Example:

```
$args = array(
  'name'         => "Color",
  'slug'         => "color",
  'order_by'     => "menu_order",
  'has_archives' => "",
);
wc_create_attribute($args);

$add = wp_insert_term( "Blue", 'pa_color', array( 'slug' => "blue" ) );
print_r($add);
```

The `wc_create_attribute()` works fine, but when the `wp_insert_term()` runs it throws an error because of “Invalid taxonomy”.
When I then reload the page, it works fine because then the taxonomy is not invalid anymore.
So it seems that the `wp_insert_term()` are executed before the create_attribute somehow. I don’t understand why it does not work in one attempt.

Maybe you can help me

Comment: `wc_create_attribute()` saves the attribute information to the database in a custom table. WooCommerce reads this table registers taxonomies for the saved attributes on the `init` hook at priority `5`. To do what you want you need to create the attribute _before_ `init` at priority `5`, and then assign to to the product _after_ `init` at priority `5`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This makes sense.  Do you have any idea & example how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't really know what you're doing exactly. What's the context of this code?

Comment: It's a functions which executes to create attributes/terms on a custom theme import because these are not imported on the demo import.

Answer (score 1):

```
wc_create_attribute( array(
    'name' => 'color',
    'type' => 'select'
) );

register_taxonomy( 'pa_color', array( 'product' ), array() );

wp_insert_term( 'Rood', 'pa_color' );
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to reregister taxonomies**

```
$args = array(
  'name'         => "Color",
  'slug'         => "color",
  'order_by'     => "menu_order",
  'has_archives' => "",
);
wc_create_attribute($args);
WC_Post_Types::register_taxonomies();

$add = wp_insert_term( "Blue", 'pa_color', array( 'slug' => "blue" ) );
print_r($add);
```